# how to call an external callback inside async?

Tags: node.js, callback, socket.io

**Problem**

I have an argument that is a callback function. When I call it inside my `async` waterfall function it isn't called. I mean this code:

**Code**

```
function myFunc(opts, callback){
var callback = callback || function () {};
...
async.waterfall(
        [async.apply(findUser, opt), function2],
        function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            };

            if (result !== undefined && result.length !== 0) {
                foundUser = result;
                callback(null, "I called callback");                
            };

        });
```

The message `I called callback` isn't call. My callback defined in my test codes inside another file. I'm using `socket io`.

I don't know where the problem is. any comment is appreciated

**Update**

My `callback` code is:

```
function myCallback (err, result) {     
        console.log("hello", "this is my callback");
        if (err) {
            console.log("err", err);
        }else{
            console.log("result is:", result);
        };      
    }
```

How I call it?

**test.js**

```
client.emit("event", message.encode().toBuffer(), myCallback);
```

(`myCallback` is defined in this file)

**index.js**

this file handle `event` event with `socket io`:

```
mongoService.myFunc(userQueryParam, callback);
```

`callback` is `myCallback` that is passed to this event handler.

**service.js**

This file has the `myFunc` definition as above.

Comment: Is the control reaching the if's body? Have a few `console.log`s inside that

Comment: Yes I did it. the control reached to that point. I don't know why the callback doesn't work :| @thefourtheye

Comment: When `myFunc` is getting called, before the `callback || ...`, can you check what the actual value of `callback`?

Comment: If you place `console.log('hello');` just above `callback(null, "I called callback");` do you see hello in terminal? If so then the problem is not in the code you posted but rather in callback function. Can you post code for it?

Comment: @thefourtheye I did it and the callback is called. I put it before and after `callback || ..` and the callback worked. `callback` is defined in `test.js` file and I pass it to a service file `service.js` and I called it inside `async` waterfall.

Comment: @Molda Yes I see. I'll update it now.

Comment: If you place `console.log(callback.toString());` above `callback(null, "I called callback");` does it output the same code you just added for myCallback? Also how do you call myFunc?

Comment: @Molda No it didn't :|. I mean it shows something else. but when I call it (`callback(null, "This message")`) it worked. I'll update my question and will add it.

Comment: If you delete this line `var callback = callback || function () {};` from myFunc do you get an error saying callback is undefined?

Comment: @Molda No it didn't.

Comment: Well if `console.log(callback.toString());` does not output the code for myCallback then you most probably overwrite it somewhere in your code. Can't really help without seeing more of your code